# Assistance needed pivot table, Countif, Averages, and tons of data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a pivot table with employees names, their grand totals of cases worked for the month, the days they worked during the month, and the case counts for each day.

I have them all stacked on top of each other on a sheet for fast viewing.

I created a column to countif Column (A) has a partial text value that matches the month.

In that column (AR) it returns 1 for true and 0 for not true.

I'm trying to create a formula where it sums up the 1s between the 0s.

The picture is horrible due to the size limits.

Basically, I need to count the days the employee worked and find the average case count for the month for each employee.

I can't use the average function in the pivot table because the count is based on IDs.

I tried If statements, and SumIfs.

[ATTACHED IS A SAMPLE OF THE FILE I'M WORKING WITH](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zu34evmnghxf37h/Example%20of%20what%20I%20am%20trying%20to%20get%20to%20work.xlsx?dl=0)

[Picture of the Spreadsheet as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwaJT.png)

Comment: I'm thinking maybe a dynamic range but not sure how ai would implement it right since every month this changes. It has to be dynamic.

Comment: I'm thinking that image is a great example of a moire pattern. do you not have screen snip?

Comment: I added a snip of the image. I hope it helps.

Comment: If you don't mind to have your pivot table layout as tabular, maybe it'll be easier for you to write the vba because with tabular layout you can reference the range of the pivot field and the pivot item - then you can offset the range to the empty column after the pivot table.  https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: I can explore that but my VBA is super weak.

Comment: I honestly can't get that to work. Is there any way I can do it with a formula or like a dynamic range or something?

Comment: I can't figure this out for the life of me. It seems so simple; yet, it evades me. If excel were a D&D character it would be a rogue.

Comment: Hi, can u send ur excel file (or a sample of it) ?

Comment: I will asap. Have to convert it to sample data since this data is for my job.

Comment: I added a link to the sample file in the original question.

Comment: Still needing assistance. I have not figured this out.

Comment: @MikeR I uploaded a sample file.

Comment: @karma I uploaded a sample file if you would like to take a look.

Comment: I've seen you sample file. To be honest I don't understand at all of your expected result and problem. Anyway, IF you know how would be the formula for your case, BUT you don't know on how to put the formula beside the pivot table, then you can make a dynamic range from the pivot table range reference by reading the link I put in my comment before. I'm limited in English, so even after I read your information, I still can't figure out how the formula would be. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm working on Excel in french. But I hope my answer with the file modified will help u understand what I'm talking about.

Here is your Excel sample with my modifications :  [Your Excel file that I modified](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20230101TAkozDuy)

You can create another pivot table, that uses your previous pivot table as new datasource. But before doing that, make sure the elements of your first column "Claimed by" is repeated, by checking the column option "repeat element labels" like this :
[image]

In this new crosstab, you add as columns : the sum of "Case Count" ; and the count of "Days".
After that, you can filter the column "Claimed by" by selecting only elements without the word "total".

Then your average will be obtained simply by dividing the two columns.
[image]